# Convert HTML input id to PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to convert the following html to php so I can use within a script I am working on.  I am not sure I have written the PHP correctly so I want to check to see if anyone can spot any errors.

Here it the html:

```
<section class="ac-container">
            <div>
                <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="radio" checked />
                <label for="ac-1">About us</label>
                <article class="ac-small">
                    <p>My Content goes here</p>
                </article>
```

Here is the PHP block:

```
 $x =1;
 echo '<section class=\"ac-container>\"';
 echo '<input id=\"ac-'$x'\"' . '' . 'name=\"accordion-1' . '' . 'type=\"radio\"' .
 'checked'.'>';
 echo '<div>';
 echo '<label for=\"ac-\"'. $x .'\"'.'>';
 echo '<h2>'.strtoupper(str_replace("_", " ",($k))).' ' . 'DEALS'.'</h2>';
 echo '</label>';
 echo '<article class=\"ac-large\">';
 echo '<p>';
 echo '</p>';
 echo '</article>';
 echo '</div>';
 echo '</section>';
 $x++;
```

I think the specific issue is with the following lines where I don't think I am formatting $x correctly?

```
 echo '<input id=\"ac-'$x'\"' . '' . 'name=\"accordion-1' . '' . 'type=\"radio\"' .
 'checked'.'>;
```

and

```
 echo '<label for=\"ac-\"'. $x .'\"'.'>';
```

Appreciate any help.

Cheers
Volterony

Comment: Why you `echo` so much HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some additional and missing double quotes. I tried to fix all. Try following code

```
 $x =1;
 echo '<section class="ac-container">';
 echo '<input id="ac-'.$x.'" name="accordion-1" type="radio" checked>';
 echo '<div>';
 echo '<label for="ac-'. $x .'"'.'>';
 echo '<h2>'.strtoupper(str_replace("_", " ",($k))).' ' . 'DEALS'.'</h2>';
 echo '</label>';
 echo '<article class="ac-large">';
 echo '<p>';
 echo '</p>';
 echo '</article>';
 echo '</div>';
 echo '</section>';
 $x++;
```

Comment: Thanks Hassan.  You were right, I did mess up the double quotes in places, however your corrections did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use backslash with double quote.

Example :

```
echo '<section class="ac-container">';
//....
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, this technique leads to unreadable code that will be a massive maintenance nightmare.

php makes it quite easy to separate logic and presentation, at the very least you could do something like this (just an example, not sure if I 100% copied your intentions):

```
<?php
    $mytitle = strtoupper(str_replace("_", " ",$k));
    $x=1;
    $mycontent = 'My Content goes here';
?>

<section class="ac-<?php echo $x; ?>">
<div>
<input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="radio" checked />
<label for="ac-1"><?php echo $mytitle; ?> DEALS</label>
<article class="ac-small">
<p><? echo $mycontent; >?</p>
</article>
```

You'll notice that this is a whole lot less intrusive, with much less php sprinkled into the HTML, and thus a lot more readable.